# How to make URL's out of this text with least resources?

Tags: sed, awk, perl

INPUT:

```
nyeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.txt:sadfsadf
sadjflsajfd:jasdlfjalsfd
foo/asdfsafd.txt:laksjdlfajsfd
```

OUTPUT:

```
<a href="nyeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.txt">nyeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.txt</a>:sadfsadf
<a href="sadjflsajfd">sadjflsajfd</a>:jasdlfjalsfd
<a href="foo/asdfsafd.txt">foo/asdfsafd.txt</a>:laksjdlfajsfd
```

So I need to convert the INPUT to OUTPUT, the difference is that OUTPUT is "clickable" because this is in a HTML file.

**Q:** How can I do this with awk, sed or perl?

I know I can do a "read line by line", but what is the most resource efficient way to do this? (I only need 1 solution, not for all sed/awk/etc.) `:` is the delimiter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly what you asked for:

```
sed 's/\([^:]\+\)/<a href="\1">\1<\/a>/' input.txt
```

```
awk -F ':' -vOFS=':' '$1="<a href=\""$1"\">"$1"</a>"' input.txt
```

```
while IFS=':' read -r url text; do echo "<a href=\"$url\">$url</a>:$text"; done < input.txt
```

But for real HTML generating you also have to take care of HTML encoding:

```
perl -MHTML::Entities -pe 's!([^:]+)(.*)!"<a href=\"".($t=encode_entities($1))."\">$t".encode_entities($2)!e' input.txt
```